# How to send multiple emails?

Tags: php, email, nette

I'm trying to send email to selected users by nette mailer but it allways results with an `InvalidStateException`.

```
public function contactsEditorFormSucceeded($form, $values)
{
        try {
            $recipients = $values->recipients;
            $mail = new Message;                      
            $mail->setFrom($values->email)
                ->setSubject($values->subject)
                ->setBody($values->message);
                foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
                    $mail->addTo($recipient);
                }
    $mailer = new SendmailMailer;
        $mailer->send($mail);
    $this->flashMessage('Done.', self::MSG_SUCCESS);
        $this->redirect('this');
        } catch (InvalidStateException $ex) {
        $this->flashMessage('Error', self::MSG_ERROR);
        }
}
```

I'm using foreach to get multiple `addTo()` but it will not send the mails.

Comment: You get an empty `InvalidStateException` exception, with no error message? On what line exactly?

Comment: Just this: $this->flashMessage('Error', self::MSG_ERROR);

Comment: That's because your `catch` block hides the exception. What do you get it you comment out the entire block (`catch` included)?

Comment: OMG I have it on localhost, that is why it did not worked. Sorry for the false alarm xD

Comment: Still, you wrote code to hide the error message :)

Answer (score 0):

Message can not have multiple recipients. It is necessary to create a cycle and create so many messages about how many recipients are

```
public function contactsEditorFormSucceeded($form, $values)
{
    try {
        $recipients = $values->recipients;

        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
            $mail = new Message;                      

            $mail->setFrom($values->email)
                ->setSubject($values->subject)
                ->setBody($values->message)
                ->addTo($recipient);

            $mailer = new SendmailMailer;
            $mailer->send($mail);
        }

        $this->flashMessage('Done.', self::MSG_SUCCESS);
        $this->redirect('this');

    } catch (InvalidStateException $ex) {
        $this->flashMessage('Error', self::MSG_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer.